# Bootswatch anchor hrefs

Tags: angularjs, bootswatch

How do we tell Angular not to try to go to a route if we simply have an anchor such as:

```
<a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
```

When we click on "Home" we're just simply hiding/showing div sections on the current view with CSS but as stated, Angular thinks we're going to a specified route which we may have set up in app.js or something.

Any ideas?

Thanks much,

David

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-target` instead of `href` to specify the target  id

```
<a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab"> Home </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to angular link rewriting explained here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Add `target="_self"` to the link to prevent it.

You should also consider Angular Directives for Bootstrap. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/